# PyInstaller 2.0 make exe file

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller

I need help to make exe file form *.py project
I use

```
python pyinstaller.py 'path to my .py'
```

but it produces file without *.exe extension. I found lots of PyInstaller 1.5 tutorials but tey doesn't work for me. e.g when I try to use makespec.py from utils I get error `no module named PyInstaller.makespec`

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a really simple script with no imports, no data files to include. Something like...

```
print 'hello world'
```

Then run pyinstaller as per the manual. For example.

```
pyinstaller.py --onedir --name=a_friendly_app_name_here   your_script.py
```

Dont touch the spec file. Save this for later once you get the basics working.

If you want to run your commands using a batch file to save lots of typing, include the 'pause' command on the next line to hold open the console window to see any errors and your output.

Once you have proved this works for you, gradually increase complexity.

Comment: Can you generate the exe on a mac?

Comment: Not sure sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The command line I use to build my exe with pyinstaller is:

```
c:\python27\python.exe c:\pyinstaller\pyinstaller.py --noconsole --onedir --workpath="C:\Users\alan\Documents\python" "C:\Users\alan\Documents\python\piechart.py"
```

Change --onedir option to --onefile if you want a stand alone exe.